# Multiple apps in git remote and how to specify to one app

Tags: django, git, heroku

I was working with another developer on my git repository and he pushed his work to me after forking. When I wanted to deploy the change of our work to Heroku, with `git push Heroku master` I get the following error. Previously it was always working when I deploy. I need to specify the app, but don't know how. I am using Django and VScode.

This is the following error:

```
Error: Multiple apps in git remotes
 ›     Usage: --remote heroku-staging
 ›        or: --app radiant-escarpment-03215
 ›     Your local git repository has more than 1 app referenced in git remotes.
 ›     Because of this, we can't determine which app you want to run this command against.
 ›     Specify the app you want with --app or --remote.
 ›     Heroku remotes in repo:
 ›     beneluxbilal (heroku)
 ›   radiant-escarpment-03215 (heroku-staging)
```

I already tried with --app but it seems not to work for me.

Answer (score 0):

> heroku ps:scale web=1 --remote heroku-staging

Comment: It is difficult to say how you are responding to the question. Could you please elaborate? Thanks.

Comment: since Heroku rebuilds the dyno after git push, choosing which origin like `heroku-staging` arg will tell Heroku from which origin to pull the code. Worked for me past.